# angular mat option cannot cast $event to object

Tags: angular, angular-material

if someone select a row in my mat select, it should be added to an array. My array is a array out of tags (customobject) unfortunately i cannot cast the $event to a tag object. Here is my 
i have also tried to use the fruit out of filteredFruits but it also doesnt work. Here is my sourcecode:

```
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="addToList($event)">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of filteredFruits | async" [value]="fruit">
            {{fruit.name}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
```

and here is my method:

```
addToList(tag: any) {
let found = false;


// tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-for-of
for (let i = 0; i < this.fruits.length; i++) {
  if (this.fruits[i].name === tag.name) {
    found = true;
    break;
  }
}
if (!found) {
  this.fruits.push(tag);
}
```

}

Comment: give sample record of `filteredFruits` and `this.fruits` too

Comment: filteredFruits: Observable<Tag[]>;

Comment: this.fruits = Tag[]

Comment: I mean records sample inside of this variable...

Comment: you mean tag: { name: string, id: String, imageUrl: string} ?